# how to divide the value in each cell of a .csv by the value in another cell across multiple rows and variables in R?

Tags: r, loops, csv, sorting, for-loop

I have a .csv file of 39 variables and 713 rows, each containing a count of plastic items. I have another column which is the survey length, and I want to standardise each count of items by a survey length of 100. I am unsure how to create a loop to run through each row and cell individually to do this. Many also have NA values.

Any ideas would be great. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying formula directly on columns without need of looping:

```
# RETRIEVE ALL COLUMN NAMES (MINUS SURVEY LENGTH)
vars <- names(df)[!grepl("survey_length", names(df))]

# EXPAND SINGLE COLUMN TO EQUAL DIMENSION OF DATA FRAME
survey_length_mat <- matrix(df$survey_length, ncol=length(vars), nrow=nrow(df))

# APPLY FORMULA
df[vars] <- (df[vars] / survey_length_mat) * 100

df
```